# Sequential Long-Text Classification with Recurrent and Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: classification, neural-networks, text-mining, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am thinking to build a model for predicting events from news. Before I start this task I wanted to ask if someone have tried to build something like in the link(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03827.pdf) but for long text(sequence of news).

I can't find any papers or example code for such a problem that's why I am wondering if at least the idea to make a binary text classification model for very long text makes sense and have a future or if it's proven that this kind of classification problem makes no sense.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for some papers that tackle long-sequence text classification (such as long articles, academic papers...) and at the moment I have only found *one* paper.

- [Long Length Document Classification by Local Convolutional Feature Aggregation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326593374_Long_Length_Document_Classification_by_Local_Convolutional_Feature_Aggregation)

It seems that there is a lack of background on this topic, as the authors do not even mention any related work in this sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Can you please summarize the main points in the paper you cited? It's will be helpful both when somebody searches the site and in case the link breaks. By the way, take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).